# iOS navigation toolbar button with image and title

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I need a toolbar button with small text under button icon.

[image: Example]

I'm trying on viewDidLoad to do:

```
UIButton* customButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[customButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-search-active.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[customButton sizeToFit];
UIBarButtonItem* sb = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:customButton];
[self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sb]];
```

But my button have only icon, no title visible.

Comment: First - Example you have shown was UITabBarController. If you want to set title on that position than above code will not work, need to create `UITabBarController`.

Second - For custom button with title you have to set `titleForEdgeInsets`.

Comment: Are you talking about the bar at the bottom of your example? That's a UITabBar, you get it by using UITabBarController

Comment: What is your issue??

Comment: I told about bar at the bottom of the image. But I cannot use the UITabBar for this purpose, I need to modify UINavigationController toolbar like in the sample .

Comment: He is not using a UITabController. He is using a toolbar that is part of the UINavigationController. @Matthias Bauch